# awk ward problem

Tags: awk

I'm trying to use awk to pull some different fields from a string.

Example:

```
selected="a2.flac|a3.flac|a4.flac"
first_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -F'|' '{print $1}')
```

The above code returns a2.flac which is what I expected.  But now, I want to iterate over a variable and pull each file out one at a time.  So I tried this:

```
i=1
first_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -F'|' '{print $i}')
```

I thought this would pull out the first file ... but nothing returns.
so I tried this next:

```
i=1
first_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -F'|' '{print \$i}')
```

This also did not work. I also tried this method:

```
i=1
first_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -F'|' n=$i '{print $n}')
```

And also tried this:

```
i=1
first_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -v -F'|' n=$i '{print $n}')
```

Nothing I've tried seems to work.  I'm at a loss on what will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you almost make it

```
i=1
first_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -v n="$i" -F'|'  '{print $n}')
```

- variable are set using -v name=value

Comment: the above solution is working nicely for me.  Based upon the solutions here, I have found a third solution that is also working (but a little convoluted):   ` input_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -F'|' "{print $\"$i\"}")`

Answer (score 4):

Your `$i` is a shell variable, `awk` has no access to it so `$i` evaluates to empty. You can either i) use double qupted for the `awk` script so that the shell expands variables within it before passing it to `awk` for execution or ii) pass it to `awk` as an `awk` variable:

- Use double quotes. Note that since the shell is now expanding variables, you'll need to escape the first `$` so that it is passed to `awk` and not interpreted by the shell:

  ```
  $ i=1
  $ first_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -F'|' "{print \$$n}")
  $ echo "$first_file"
  a2.flac
  ```
- Pass the variable to `awk`. You had the syntax *almost* right:

  ```
  $ first_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -F'|' -vi="$i" '{print $i}')
  $ echo "$first_file"
  a2.flac
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The value of $i is set by the shell, to be able to do that, the string must be either double quoted or unquoted. Thus, your line:

```sh
i=1; first_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -F'|' '{print $i}')     # original
i=1; first_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -F'|' '{print $'$i'}')  # un-quoted
i=1; first_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -F'|' '{print $'"$i"'}') # double-quoted
i=1; first_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -F'|' "{print \$$i}")  # full double-quoted
```

Of course, you could, and is the most correct way to do it, tell awk what is the value of the var, and use it ( I used jj to make the difference in variable names explicit):

```sh
i=1; first_file=$(echo "$selected" | awk -F'|' -v jj="$i" '{print $jj}')
```

Perhaps a more idiomatic way will be (no sub-shell because of pipe "|"):

```sh
i=1; first_file="$( <<<"$selected" awk -F\| '{print $'$i'}')"
```